# iMessage Crashes and Causes my iPod to Shut Down

Tags: ipod-touch

I have an iPod touch 4th gen and whenever I go onto imessage, it first crashes about twice, then on the third time or so, it causes my iPod to turn off completely. This happened after I someone gave me thier contact info and I tried texting them for the first time. After that, the app didn't open again.

Answer (score 1):

I would try and go on contacts and try to send a message from there. Also, you could always use a font app and send a text. (It worked when my iPhone did the same thing)